# Show only digits result from hdparm command

Tags: bash, monitoring, snmp, cacti

I need get only digit result for my MIB from hdparm output.

Example. I get hdparm info about my device.

```
hdparm -t /dev/sda1

/dev/sda1:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 220 MB in  3.02 seconds =  72.88 MB/sec
```

How i get only `72.88` from this command. I need this for my bash script and SNMP monitoring?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the `hdparm` doesn't give any script-friendly output. You will have to resort to `tail` and `sed`:

```
sudo hdparm -t /dev/sda1 |tail -n 1 |sed -s 's/.*=\s\([0-9\.]\+\) MB.*/\1/'
```

Result:

```
$ sudo hdparm -t /dev/sda1 |tail -n 1 |sed -s 's/.*=\s\([0-9\.]\+\) MB.*/\1/'
470.51
```

Comment: Sorry, but this not work for me


`root@Bitrix24app:~# sudo hdparm -t /dev/sda1 |tail -n 1 |sed -s 's/.*=\s\([0-9\.]\+\) MB.*/\1/'
 Timing buffered disk reads: 236 MB in  3.00 seconds =  78.60 MB/sec`

Comment: Well, it works for me, even when I use your string for testing. You'll have to build your own expression for sed then.